# Fastest solution to proving cross-dot product relationship

Tags: vectors

I have to prove the relationship between dot and cross product via 
$|a \times  b|^2=a^2b^2 - (a.b)^2$

There have found different ways to prove it, but which is the fastest one? I have tried expanding everything and proving it takes me ~10min, which I believe is not very efficient. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are allowed to use $|\mathbf a \times \mathbf b |= \mathbf{|a||b|}\sin\theta$

Then it comes from $\sin^2 \theta +\cos^2 \theta =1$