# Let $a$ and $b$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $|a\times b|=10$ and $a\cdot b=−4$. Determine $|a|^2|b|^2$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Let $a$ and $b$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $|a\times b|=10$ and $a\cdot b=−4$. Determine $|a|^2|b|^2$.

I tried to solve the problem using the definition of the dot and cross product and then multiplied them, while substituting values. However I got $-\frac{40}{\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}=|a|^2\cdot |b|^2$ but I can't find out $\theta$. Can someone help to solve the rest of the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest solution to proving cross-dot product relationship](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749278)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$|a|^2|b|^2 = |a|^2|b|^2 \sin^2\theta + |a|^2|b|^2  \cos^2\theta = |a\times b|^2 + |a.b|^2$$

Comment: So I used the trigonometric identity and I got 116. Was that the answer?

Comment: That is correct.